# get the url <img src=''> a rss feed and open on <image> in xaml Windos Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, rss, feed

I have this class:

```
class clsFeed
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public string PublishDate { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public Uri Link { get; set; }
    }
```

and I need to get the tag  that lies within the tag  http://www.unnu.com/feed and open this address on my main page in the list with the other data. This is the code I'm using. It compiles but seems to me he's always been empty.

```
private void UpdateFeedList(string feedXML)
        {
            // Load the feed into a SyndicationFeed instance
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(feedXML);
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
            SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);

            //var counter = feed.Items.Count();
            var lista = feed.Items.ToList().Select(s => new clsFeed
            {
                Title = s.Title.Text,
                Summary = s.Summary.Text,
                PublishDate = s.PublishDate.Date.ToString(),
                Content = "",
                Imagem = s.Summary.Text.Split('<')[5].Replace("img src='", "").Replace("' border='0' />", ""),
                Link = s.Links.FirstOrDefault().Uri
            }).ToList();


                      Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                // Bind the list of SyndicationItems to our ListBox
                feedListBox.ItemsSource = lista;
                feedListBox.ItemsSource = feed.Items;
                //progressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            });
            //gridProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;   //Quando atualiza a lista de feeds esconde a progress bar.
            panorama.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

---

```
private void UpdateFeedList(string feedXML)
    {
        // Load the feed into a SyndicationFeed instance
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(feedXML);
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);



        // In Windows Phone OS 7.1, WebClient events are raised on the same type of thread they were called upon. 
        // For example, if WebClient was run on a background thread, the event would be raised on the background thread. 
        // While WebClient can raise an event on the UI thread if called from the UI thread, a best practice is to always 
        // use the Dispatcher to update the UI. This keeps the UI thread free from heavy processing.
        var lista = feed.Items.ToList().Select(s => new clsFeed
        {
            Title = s.Title.Text,
            Summary = s.Summary.Text,
            PublishDate = s.PublishDate.Date.ToString(),
            Content = "",                
            Imagem = Regex.Match(feedXML, @"<img\s+src='(.+)'\s+border='0'\s+/>").Groups[1].Value,
            Link = s.Links.FirstOrDefault().Uri
        }).ToList();




        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // Bind the list of SyndicationItems to our ListBox
            feedListBox.ItemsSource = lista;


        });

        gridProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;   //Quando atualiza a lista de feeds esconde a progress bar.
        panorama.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

This works but nothing appears on the screen. Does anyone know why?

My listbox remains the same.

---

Dont have any erros.

```
<ListBox x:Name="feedListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="537" Margin="10,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="398" SelectionChanged="listFeedBox_SelectionChanged" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Grid>
                                    <Image Width="400" Height="130" Name="img" Source="{Binding feed.ImageUrl}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" FontSize="24" Name="feedTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Title.Text, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmer}}" >
                                        <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF159DDE"/>
                                        </TextBlock.Foreground>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Name="feedSummary" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Summary.Text, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmer}}" />
                                    <TextBlock Name="feedPubDate" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" Margin="12,0,0,10" Text="{Binding PublishDate}" />
                                    <TextBlock Name="feedContent" Text="{Binding Content}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                           </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Comment: What is empty? I've tested your code and it returns 50 elements so "lista" is good. If the issue is with the ListBox how is it defined?

Comment: the image does not appear

Comment: Why {Binding feed.ImageUrl} and not something like {Binding Image}? Anyway seems like SL does not play well with image URL and it need some help: http://vivekdalvi.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/binding-to-image-source/ it's really strange, such a basic stuff buggy can't believe it :( Have a try at the workaround and give us your feedback... (see here too: http://www.nullskull.com/faq/8/silverlight-ivalueconverter-for-image-urls.aspx)

Comment: the binding is not picking up that something is wrong with the class reading ... check if the attributes of the object with a message box for example. Works perfectly. But the problem continues.

Comment: Have you tried the workaround presented in the two links?

Comment: not, I'll try it today and return here with feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your heuristic to parse the image URL is brittle, you should use a regex:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
Image = Regex.Match(s.Summary.Text, @"<img\s+src='(.+)'\s+border='0'\s+/>").Groups[1].Value,
```

Comment: my image code is:

<Image Width="400" Height="130" Name="img" Source="{Binding Imagem}" />


This code don't show the image on screen... =/

Comment: vis not seeking any of the fields of the class, no image, no link or anything.

Comment: I guess "Imagem" instead of "Image" is just a typo in your comment. Moreover is the "feedListBox.ItemsSource = feed.Items" line correctly commented?

Comment: I just changed the picture for you to understand why image is in Portuguese. I managed to open the images with what you said but did not appear on the screen. If I touch the dark part of the screen it opens what I want. But I can not see the items. The commented part is not what we need. This commentary is part of SyndicationFeed that takes no image created by this class. To take all the image properties and more.

Comment: I mean "Imagem" is not consistent with your class definition at the top of your post where you use "Image" :) Anyway I've never used the W7 stuff but I guess in the XAML you add some "Image" control with the "Source" property set with the URL like in WPF or Silverlight. How does your XAML template for the ListBox looks like?

Comment: this is my listbox. 

<ListBox x:Name="feedListBox">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <stackpanel>
                       </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

Comment: inside the stackpanel have my textblocks and image. Binding with the class proprieties.

Comment: Some XAML code would help, you don't have any error in the output?

Comment: I can not paste the code here in the comments, I'll add an answer.